# how to install Network Manager on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, gcm-network-manager

Can anyone help me to install network-manager-l2tp on ubuntu 16.04?

I get this error:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 network-manager-l2tp : Depends: xl2tpd (>= 1.3.6+dfsg-4ubuntu0.16.04.1) but 1.3.6+dfsg-4 is to be installed

I also tried this answer:
https://github.com/nm-l2tp/NetworkManager-l2tp/issues/113

Comment: Hi Shahab - you will want to post this on https://serverfault.com or https://unix.stackexchange.com instead as it would be more appropriate there. Regardless of the final destination of this question, you should take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You should change your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, and put the following :

```
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

Then in the terminal, do

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp
sudo apt update
sudo apt install network-manager-l2tp -y
sudo apt install network-manager-l2tp-gnome -y
```